# Is there a way to Implement Polymorphic Relation with Doctrine 2 in Symfony 4

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, polymorphic-associations

At the basic level, I want to have an `invoice` entity , that can have and `InvoiceTo` field. The `InvoiceTo` field should be having a `ManyToOne` relation to either the `IndividualCustomer` entity or the `CompanyCustomer` entity.

All the reading so far has led me to believe that this a case for Doctrine Inheritance Mapping, but its just that I am not able to make any sense for the documentation or the very few blogs that I have found so far that discuss polymorphic relations in doctrine.

I would like to achieve it as below (**if at all that is possible**),

```php
// First Example, were the invoice is sent to an IndividualCustomer
$individualCustomer = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(individualCustomer::class)
        ->find($id);

$invoiceTo = new InvoiceTo($individualCustomer);

$invoice = new Invoice();
$invoice->setAmt(100.00);
$invoice->setInvoiceTo($invoiceTo);


// Second Example, were the invoice is sent to CompanyCustomer
$companyCustomer = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(companyCustomer::class)
        ->find($id);

$invoiceTo = new InvoiceTo($companyCustomer);

$invoice = new Invoice();
$invoice->setAmt(100.00);
$invoice->setInvoiceTo($invoiceTo);
```

I would really appreciate any kind of pointer for the same. All documentation seems very cryptic for some reason. Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: why not just make two many-to-one properties in InvoiceTo and make the constructor (and/or getter/setter) a bit *smart*, such that it checks for class and assigns the value to the correct property (and/or looks which property is set)? Inheritance mapping is not a good fit, if you want "simpler" associations. However, a quite small amount of code can go very far

Comment: @Jakumi thanks for the pointer it does make sense for such a simpler association. Any rough idea on how would querying work or be affected for such implementation. I wanted to go the `Inheritance mapping` way coz alot of it would be taken care properly by doctrine (**I Guess**).

Comment: To be honest, I tried to use inheritance mapping like ... two times. And both times I ended up wasting sooo much time trying to get doctrine to do what I wanted and both times additional fields and some very simple logic was way easier in the end. There are actually some questions I've seen recently, concerning inheritance mapping, and there are probably tutorials as well. I can't give better/specific pointers though, sorry ;o/

Comment: I'd say it's possible, but as it stands your question is too generic. Is there any specific thing you can't make out from the docs? Could you give a rough idea on your entities?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your field `invoiceTo` referencing whether an `IndividualCustomer` or a `CompanyCustomer`, a solution is to create a parent class; let's say `Customer`, from which the `IndividualCustomer` and `CompanyCustomer` inherit. 
From there, your `invoiceTo` field can directly target `Customer`.